# Java - Robustness and Code Reuse

Tags: java, code-reuse, robust

I have a few doubts on java concepts:

1. Is code reuse in java similar to using functions as defined in other programming languages like C?
2. Is Java robust by nature or does it provide a way to write robust code ?

*Can anyone explain the above two. I have read a few books and I did not get a clear picture*

Comment: code reuse - yes, you write object oriented modular code so its reusable, in a way similar to how you would create functions and reuse in C. Is java robust? The *JVM* is very robust, it has a fantastic optimized garbage collector that manages the memory for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code Reuse**

I do like to point you to some links on this topic.

- [A Realistic Look at Object-Oriented Reuse](http://drdobbs.com/184415594)
- [What exactly is OO reuse?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53521/32314)
- [Does OOP fulfill the promise of code reuse? What alternatives are there to achieve code reuse?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7618/32314)
- [Is code reuse a lie?](http://bytebaker.com/2009/07/20/is-code-reuse-a-lie/)

Some points about code reuse from the first link.

> Code reuse, the most common kind of reuse,  refers to the reuse of
>   source code within sections of an application  and potentially across
>   multiple applications. At its best, code reuse is accomplished by
>   sharing common classes or  collections of functions and procedures. At
>   its worst, code reuse is   accomplished by copying and then modifying
>   existing code.  A sad reality of our industry is that code copying is
>   often  the only form of reuse practised by developers.

**Robust**

Quoted from Core Java, Volume I, Fundamentals.

> "Java is intended for writing programs that must be reliable in a
>   variety of ways. Java puts a lot of emphasis on early checking for
>   possible problems, later dynamic (runtime) checking, and eliminating
>   situations that are error-prone. . . . The single biggest difference
>   between Java and C/C++ is that Java has a pointer model that 
>   eliminates the possibility of overwriting memory and corrupting data."
>
> This feature is also very useful. The Java compiler detects many
>   problems that, in other languages, would show up only at runtime. As
>   for the second point, anyone who has spent hours chasing memory
>   corruption caused by a pointer bug will be very happy with this
>   feature of Java.
>
> If you are coming from a language like Visual Basic that doesn’t
>   explicitly use pointers, you are probably wondering why this is so
>   important. C programmers are not so lucky. They need pointers to
>   access strings, arrays, objects, and even files. In Visual Basic, you
>   do not use pointers for any of these entities, nor do you need to
>   worry about memory allocation for them. On the other hand, many data
>   structures are difficult to implement in a pointerless language. Java
>   gives you the best of both worlds. You do not need  pointers for
>   everyday constructs like strings and arrays. You have the power of
>   pointers if you need it, for example, for linked lists. And you always
>   have complete safety, because you can never access a bad pointer, make
>   memory allocation errors, or have to protect against memory leaking
>   away.

Answer (score 0):

If by "code reuse" you mean including other files from the same project: yes. Otherwise, no.

As for the second, Java is robust, as taken from here: http://java.sun.com/docs/overviews/java/java-overview-1.html:

```
Java: A simple, object-oriented, network-savvy, interpreted, robust,
    secure, architecture neutral, portable, high-performance, multithreaded,
    dynamic language.
```

Comment: as @aishwarya said, you can use other projects in both Java and C, but Java has different procedures.